# Unity: copy file from  Unity project to android sdcard

Tags: android, file, copy, unity-game-engine

in my android unity project, there is a file named `file.txt`, the path is `Plugins/Android/assets/`. I wanna copy it to my android's sdcard eg: `/mnt/sdcard/`
how to do that using Javascript or C#?